# Variable is not read

Tags: java, variables, boolean

The part of the code where (cancel1 = 2) the boolean 'cancel' is not read:

```
while (done !=0){
  pizzaChoice = readInt ("Choose the type of pizza you wish to order");
  double quantity = readInt ("How many " + type[pizzaChoice] + " pizzas do you wish to buy (Maximum pizzas per order is 5)");   

  if(quantity >= max){
    System.out.println("Sorry you cannot order more than five pizzas");


    if ((quantity - max) <= 0){
      double pizzasLeft = max - quantity;

      System.out.println("You can still order " + pizzasLeft + " pizzas");

      pizzasLeft2 = pizzasLeft2 - pizzasLeft;
```

this next if loop is where the problem is

```
              if (pizzasLeft2 <= 0){
                boolean cancel = true;
                int cancel1 = readInt("Press 2 to cancel your order and start again"); 
                if(cancel1 == 2){
                  cancel = false;
                }

              }
            }
          }

          done= readInt ("Press 0 if you are done or press 1 to make another pizza order");
          double total1 = quantity*price[pizzaChoice];
          total2 = total2 + total1;
        }
```

Comment: The `boolean` named `cancel` is only assigned to, it is never read. What is its purpose? Do you have another `boolean` named `cancel` elsewhere and are accidentally redeclaring it, hiding the other one?

Comment: `double` is a real strange choice for number of pizzas. Can your customers order 1.2 pizzas?

Comment: why is that boolean cancel??, and what is pizzasLeft2?, is it entering the first if?, by the way, you declared cancel, inside 'if'

Comment: @Mat Sorry, that is just a typo

Answer (score 2):

The code related to `cancel` seems correct to me.
I recommend you to check the block where it has this value.
Is the condition being satisfied to enter the `if` block in the first place?
A hint is that another cancel global variable might be creating an ambiguity to its role.

Answer (score 1):

You're complaining that Eclipse, or whatever IDE you're using is complaining that `cancel` is never used right? This happens because, even if you're assigning the cancel variable values (true and false), you're never using it, like:

```
if (cancel) {
    System.out.printLn("Thanks for visiting Java Pizza!");
}
```

If you use it in some way in your code, the warning goes away. Or if you remove it of your code, since its useless the way it is